# Using CustomRepository implemention with spring boot & spring-data-jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

**Background**

I'm trying to create a custom implementation for my spring boot data jpa application.

I've created a `UserRepsitoryCustom` interface with "`List<User> getUsers(String type)`" method.

I've created a `UserRepository` interface with extends `CrudRepository<User, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<User>, UserRepositoryCustom`.

I've created a `UserRepositoryImpl` class which extends `UserRepositoryCustom` interface and implements the "`getUsers(String type)`" method.

**Problem**

My expectation was that spring *boot-data-jpa* will create me a repository bean that combines all the goodies from `CrudRepository` & `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` and additional will know to use my custom implementation repository.

Currently, all I'm getting is

> PropertyReferenceException: No property getUsers found...

I haven't annotated the `UserRepositoryImpl` with any `@Component` or `@Repository`. and I haven't changed any default configuration.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Try it with `@Transactional` at your ´UserRepository interface`. But your code will help a lot to help you

Comment: according to your question you are doing everything correct. But obviously that cannot be the case as you are having the error. follow these steps again http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour. if you still face the issue. post the source codes. Also make sure you have not changed the configuration for repository impl postfix.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my problem!!! The UserRepositoryImpl was in the wrong package name... I've moved it to the right package name and it's done!